# Expo: Can't change Android Standalone App Icon and Name

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I am trying to change the icon and the name of my expo managed app. I changed the files in assets to contain my images. They are located at assets/images. The names of the files are correct, if I Ctrl+Click on them, I get to the correct file. I also changed "name" to be the new name. My **app.json** looks like this:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "userInterfaceStyle": "automatic",
    "name": "GroupStatus",
    "slug": "GroupStatus",
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/images/my-icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/images/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "usesAppleSignIn": true,
      "requireFullScreen": true,
      "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
      "buildNumber": "2.0.0"
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "com.myName.groupstatus",
      "googleServicesFile": "./google-services.json",
      "versionCode": 3,
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/images/my-adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      },
      "icon": "./assets/images/my-icon.png",
      "userInterfaceStyle": "dark"
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/images/favicon.png"
    },
    "scheme": "groupstatus"
  }
}
```

I also have an **app.config.ts** file:

```
import "dotenv/config";

export default {
  extra: {
    apiKey: process.env.API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.AUTH_DOMAIN,
    projectId: process.env.PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    appId: process.env.APP_ID,
    measurementId: process.env.MEASURING_ID,
    databaseUrl: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
  },
  facebookScheme: "12345",
  slug: "GroupStatus",
  title: "GroupStatus",
  android: {
    package: "com.myName.groupstatus",
    versionCode: 3,
  },
};
```

When I build the app as an apk/aab I get the old name and the default icons.

I am using Expo SDK 42.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. If you use app.config.js along side app.json, you have to tell your app.config.js file to include the values in app.json.

```
export default ({ config }: ConfigConte) => {
  const apiKey = process.env.API_KEY!;
  const authDomain = process.env.AUTH_DOMAIN!;
  const projectId = process.env.PROJECT_ID!;
  const storageBucket = process.env.STORAGE_BUCKET!;
  const messagingSenderId = process.env.MESSAGING_SENDER_ID!;
  const appId = process.env.APP_ID!;
  const measurementId = process.env.MEASURING_ID!;
  const databaseUrl = process.env.DATABASE_URL!;

  return {
    ...config,    // <= this includes all the values from app.json
    extra: {
      apiKey,
      authDomain,
      projectId,
      storageBucket,
      messagingSenderId,
      appId,
      measurementId,
      databaseUrl,
    },
  };
};
```

Without including the configs, all values set in app.json will not be applied.
For more on this read the [docs](https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/configuration/):